# How do I startup Xserve OS X without the GUI?

Tags: mac-osx, mac-osx-server, xserve

I'd like to start-up Xserves at Unix run level 3. At least turn off the GUI and have all the service app (networking, ssh, apache, mysql, etc.) running in the background. Is this possible? How do I configure this?

Comment: BTW: I'm aware of how to boot into single user, which is not my intent. I want *nix runlevel 3 at the end of the day if possible.

Answer (score 1):

OS X does not have runlevels. It natively boots into the GUI. If you want you can set the server to not auto-login and just list the username and password fields on boot. From there you can type ">console" in the user field and press return. This will exit the GUI and drop you into a shell.

May I ask what you want to accomplish by booting into "runlevel 3"?

Comment: Avoid the GUI ram/cpu overhead.

Comment: Trust me when I say that the GUI is the least of your worries when it comes to OS X Server. Apple File Server usually takes up 100% of the CPU all the time regardless! :P